# Need a way to have templated constants of any type in a header only library

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, constants

```
goals:
1. store constants with their assignments in a header
2. keep constants in a namespace (without using #define)
3. allow constants to be whatever precision is needed for the app
```

I am trying to keep all constants for my header only library in the same namespace. I decided to do away with `#define`s and do things the right way, such as using:

```
namespace studio
{
    namespace constant
    {
        const char* WHITE_SPACE = "\n\r\t ";
    }
}
```

The hope is to access this like so:
`studio::constant::WHITE_SPACE`

*This is all fine and good, from what I have gathered, doing it this way creates one of these for each translation unit, potentially to be optimized down to a single instance during linking. Even if it is not optimized like that, it is probably okay in this case.*

The trouble comes when I want to add other types besides const char * as constants. For example, say I want to allow a float type (double or float) as a constant, but I would like to do it as a template so I don't have to do something like:

```
namespace studio
{
    namespace constant
    {
         const char* WHITE_SPACE = "\n\r\t ";
         const float PI_FLOAT = 3.141592653589793;
         const double PI_DOUBLE = 3.141592653589793;
    }
}
```

So I tried using a templated class instead of a namespace, with static functions which return the static constant like so:

```
namespace studio
{
    template <class FloatType = float>
    class constant
    {
    public:
        static const char* white_space_chars() {
            static const char* whiteSpaceChars = "\n\r\t ";
            return whiteSpaceChars;
        }
        static const FloatType pi() {
            static const FloatType _pi = 3.141592653589793;
            return _pi;
        }
    }
}
```

This would then be accessed this way: `studio::constant<float>::pi()`

But now I have the problem where I have to supply a template parameter if I want one of my const chars even though they have nothing to do with floats, they must be accessed like so:
`studio::constant<float>::white_space_chars()`
because
`studio::constant::white_space_chars()`
does not work, even though I specified a default template parameter, apparently that only works for classes. C++ does not allow defaults on function templates.

So now the only way I can see to get around this is to have studio::constant_char, studio::constant_float, studio::constant_int, etc. That is ridiculous, right?

Really all I want is to have my defines in a namespace...

Do you know a better way to do what I am trying to do, where variables of different types can be used template like in the studio::constant namespace without forcing the user of the library to specify the type for each template parameter? Preferably not using C++11 to be more backward compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the template onto the static methods that actually use it:

```
namespace studio
{
    class constant
    {
    public:
        static const char* white_space_chars() {
            return "\n\r\t ";
        }

        template <class FloatType = float>
        static const FloatType pi() {
            return FloatType(3.141592653589793);
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
float flt_pi = studio::constant::pi();
double dbl_pi = studio::constant::pi<double>();
```

Comment: you can only do `float flt_pi = studio::constant::pi()` in C++11. Anything prior to C++11 does not allow default template arguments for functions :( Though this does get the char* case working without a template argument :)

Comment: I do not have a C++11 compiler and I'm pretty sure I've used default template parameters before.  I do know for sure that if the template function takes an output parameter by pointer/reference then the compiler can infer the template parameter for you: `template <class FloatType>
static void pi(FloatType &val) { val = FloatType(3.141592653589793); }` `float flt_pi; studio::constant::pi(flt_pi);`

Comment: Ahh you are correct, it was added in C++0x. I was testing in Visual Studio 2010, which apparently is only a partial implementation of C++0x.

Comment: I decided to use this static template method style. It really seems like the most flexible/controllable option. I love that you are not restricted to one type such as in a `#define` and in fact really like being able to specify the exact type you want. Also, because you are constructing a function, you can also have more complicated constants. For example, you could initialize a static variable with a more complicated function once and simply return the static as the constant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could be done by having an override-able define such as:

```
#ifndef STUDIO_FLOAT_TYPE
typedef float STUDIO_FLOAT_TYPE;
#endif

namespace studio
{
    namespace constant
    {
         const char* WHITE_SPACE = "\n\r\t ";
         const STUDIO_FLOAT_TYPE PI = 3.141592653589793;
    }
}
```

Which would allow the user to override the float type before including the library header. At least there's only one define and it still has a default.

Because surely a define like this would be used in other headers, I suppose it might be nice to keep all the customizable defines in a single header that all the individual library headers refer to.

Comment: I see now that one of the disadvantages of this is that you can only use one or the other but not both in the same project, where with templates you could use both depending on the precision context. Template functions may be syntactically large, but it might be worth it for flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, in C++14 you can do:

```
template <typename T>
const T PI = T(3.141592653589793);
```

See [variable templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Variable_templates).

As an example:

```
// header.h
namespace constant
{
  template <typename T>
  constexpr T PI = T(3.141592653589793);
}

void foo();
```

```
// foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

void foo() {
    std::cout << constant::PI<int> << std::endl;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
  std::cout << constant::PI<float> << std::endl;
  foo();
}
```

This gives the output:

```
3.14159
3
```